# Reading Json Data in Javascript / php (Format issue)

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this code which reads the json data below (This code works well):

```
var data = [{"id":1, "start":"2011-10-29T13:15:00.000+10:00", "end":"2011-10-29T14:15:00.000+10:00", "title":"Meeting"}];

var output = '';

$.each(data, function(index, value){

    output += '<li>' + value.title + '</li>';
});
```

Ive now changed the data (see below) and for some reason it's not working

```
var data = {"users":[{"firstname":"peter","lastname":"tosh"},{"firstname":"mike","lastname":"Marsh"}]}

var output = '';

$.each(data, function(index, value){

    output += '<li>' + value.firstname + '</li>';
});
```

I know the data format is slightly different ... I'm I forgetting something?

Comment: Your code looks exactly like JavaScript, are you sure your PHP tag and title is right?

Comment: `data` is no longer an array ... but you're trying to use it as if it were.

Comment: Added Javascript to the Question tag...Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.each(data.users, function(index, value){
        output += '<li>' + value.firstname + '</li>';
 });
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

Although your code is in javascript and not PHP. The problem is that you're having an array inside of an array. So on the first loop your only getting users and not firstName or something like that. Fix:

```
var data = {"users":
            [
                {"firstname":"peter","lastname":"tosh"},
                {"firstname":"mike","lastname":"Marsh"}
            ]
           }

var output = '';

$.each(data, function(i, users){
    $.each(users, function(index, value) {
        output += '<li>' + value.firstname + '</li>';
    });
});
```